# Flatlist inside tabs not renedering properly

Tags: react-native

I am using tabs component from nativebase.io .
I want to display flatlist in one tab.
In that flatlist srcolling is not working properly lastitems are not dispaying.

Here is my code

```html
<Tabs>
    <Tab>
        <FlatList
            data={this.state.notes}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) =>
                <View>{item.note}</View>
            }
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            extraData={this.state.notes}
            ListEmptyComponent={<ErrorMessage />}
        />
    </Tab>
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `Flatlist` inside a `View` with the view's style having `flex:1`. If it does not work add `marginBottom` to `flatlist`

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
</View>
```

Comment: I tried like this also but it does not worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping it in the native base Content component, with the following style, worked for me (beware not to wrap Tab inside Content, that was my mistake):

```
<Tabs>
    <Tab>
        <Content style={{flex: 1}} contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}>
            // your FlatList here
        </Content>
    </Tab>
</Tabs>
```